# IBM FileNet P8 Java APIs integration with Android?

Tags: java, android, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

IBM FileNet P8 provides Java APIs to deal with the content engine (CE)

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.p8.ce.dev.cews.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fintroduction.htm

my question is: are these APIs compatible with Android? can I use these APIs within my Android application ? if not, are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try to use CEWS API.
2. You cat try to use CMIS interface (if CMIS can cover your requirements and if you find the impelemntations of CMIS cliet for Android)
3. You can use ready Content Navigator application from Google Play to work with P8 repository.
4. You can customize ICN and use it in mobile browser or embeded via JavaScript in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You have another option. Build a webservices layer over Filenet API and consume those webservices from your Android app

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i can't put comments to answers.

**Sherif Ayad**, FN have full WS API, it calls WSI. WS API is additional layer on EJB API. When you use CE Java API it depends on connection URL which transport will be used for communication (if protocol section of URL contains http(s) web services over http will be used, if iiop CE Java API will use CORBA(RMI) protocol for comminication) but it is the same api. WSI translate all methods to EJB layer. CE always have WS Interface. CE .NET API just generated stubs for WSI.

Development of additional layer of WS it is additional costs and source of errors.

**Mina Samy.** If you need just add comments to documents, look for the JavaScript API of ICN, or try to use ICN mobile application instead of custom application. You can try to change ICN mobile application by WebSphere Worklight technology (see license agreement for IBM Content Navigator).

**mbonaci**, FN Java API conatin some classes from Java EE stack, it use JAAS, RMI (IIOP) to work with EJB, it use some extensions of WS (WS-Security and WS-MTOM), it supports of transactions and others.

For example you need additional classes from javax.*** and some proprietary classes from WebSphere client to use CE Java API from remote host.

So, i'm not sure that CE API will be works under Android JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that wouldn't work. 
Have you tried?

The alternative could be to use phonegap and browser (like modified Workplace), but under the cover it would stll be using CE API.

What kind of client app do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to connect to a FileNet Server to view documents and add some comments, please check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818993/ibm-filenet-net-api-integration-with-windows-8

Comment: The only option with .NET is to use .NET API, which under the hood uses Web Services. If you get stuck with weird errors when you try to consume web services, try to install Microsoft Web Services Enhancements - WSE (FEM requires it so you may have already installed it). Good luck and keep us posted :)